# Как заставить проиграть gif ещё раз?

Tags: изображения, javascript, анимация

Добрый вечер, котятки, есть

```
<img src="mygif.gif" id="eyes">
```

там маленькая гифка с анимацией глаз, и колвом повторения 1 раз.
хочу по `setInterval` через ява скрипт заставить её проигрывться заново, как "гуманно" заставить проиграться ещё раз? Только релоад?

ах да код если что:

```
play=setInterval("gifa()", 5000);

function gifa() {
    $('#yash').attr('src', 'art/eyes.gif');
    x=Math.floor(Math.random() * (5)) + 1;

    clearInterval(play);
    play=setInterval("gifa()", x*1000);
}
```

Comment: Как-то так http://goo.gl/6knEH

Comment: а код с запашком...

Comment: @AlexWindHope я считаю себя новичком и с радостью приму критику,скажите пожалуйста, что не так...

Comment: если что код: http://jsfiddle.net/vT9yh/ но почему то не работает в jsfiddle в браузере норм

Comment: Правильно говорить джифка http://www.olsenhome.com/gif/

Comment: @dzhioev: ну, правильно говорить "пайтон" и "си-плас-плас", но никто ж не говорит. а mp3 вообще правильно читать "эм-пэ-драй", разработан-то он в Германии.

Comment: Эм-пе-драй фон Фраунхофер гемахт :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
var i = 0;
var timer = setInterval(function(){
    i++;
    $('#yash').attr('src','http://ul.hol.es/eyes.gif');
    // если надо ограничение на кол-во итераций, то:
    if(i > 3){
        clearInterval(timer);
    }
}, 2000);
```

На  jsfiddle.net [пример работает](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/vT9yh/1/)

Comment: единственное, как объекту timer задать случайное время промежутком от 1000 до 5000 скажем?

Comment: Закинуть код в функцию и зациклить. Только в этом случае, надо использовать не **setInterval**, а **setTimeout**:    function startAnimate(r){        setTimeout(function(){            $('#yash').attr('src','http://ul.hol.es/eyes.gif');            startAnimate(Math.floor( Math.random() * 3 ) + 1);        }, 1000 * r);    }    startAnimate(5);Т.е. получим [такую картину](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/vT9yh/2/).

Answer (score 0):

Насколько я знаю js тут вообще не причем. Закицленность выставляется в самом изображении gif.

Comment: вы правы, мне нужно заставить "сбросить" анимацию чтобы она сыграла заново

Comment: забавный факт состоит в том, что зацикленное изображение работает не везде (по крайней мере я пробовал сделать это несколько раз и все попытки были неудачными)

Comment: можно подробнее в чем именно была "неудача"?